# how to extract specific div from other website and display on my site?

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed

please help me out on this, I really stuck on this. I want to embed one specific div(I know the ID), his name is: 'content' from this website: http://www.meteox.com/forecastloop.aspx?type=2&continent=europa
I try many different method, but with no results, one is this:

```
<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
var div = document.getElementById("PlaceToPutTable");
div.innerHTML = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
</script>

<div id="PlaceToPutTable"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.meteox.com/forecastloop.aspx?type=2&continent=europa"></iframe>
```

please help me out on this, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the contents of the iframe because it is cross-domain. There are some other issues, for example you are trying to fetch iframe content which is not loaded.

I suggest fetching the document asynchronously, perhaps using jQuery, instead of using an iframe.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but how can I do this with jquery?